# Does non-matching arm take the owner of a variable in a "match" statement in Rust?

Tags: rust, match, ownership

I'm new to Rust. Below is my testing.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Food {
    Cake,
    Pizza,
    Salad,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bag {
    food: Food
}

fn main() {
    let bag = Bag { food: Food::Cake };
    match bag.food {
        Food::Cake => println!("I got cake"),
        x => println!("I got {:?}", x)
    }

    println!("{:?}", bag);
}
```

When I run it, I got an error.

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `bag`
  --> src\main.rs:20:22
   |
17 |         x => println!("I got {:?}", x)
   |         - value moved here
...
20 |     println!("{:?}", bag);
   |                      ^^^ value borrowed here after partial move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `bag.food` has type `Food`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

It's clear that `bag.food` will not match `x` arm in the code. Why a *move* happens there?

Comment: Its telling you on the "note:"

Comment: This has nothing to do with the arms, when you match something, it is moved (or copied, if possible).

Comment: Either way you borrowing the `x` there because you have to  in order  to ensure that nothing changes down the road of the program. This prevents weird things from happening like null pointers

Comment: Just to make sure we understand your question correctly: Why do you think "it's clear that `bag.food` will not match `x` arm in the code"? Because of the specific value you assigned to `bag.food`, or for some other reason?

Comment: @SvenMarnach Because of the specific value assigned, which is `Food::Cake`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter that the `x` branch is not taken at runtime because whether a `match` takes ownership of its argument does not depend on which branch of the `match` will actually be taken. Much like in this code (also see [this followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222703/if-statement-gets-executed-when-the-condition-is-false-in-a-rust-program-ho)):

```
let foo = "blargh".to_owned();
if false {
    let _bar = foo;
}
println!("{}", foo); // error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `foo`
```

`foo` is never actually moved, but that doesn't make any difference to whether it is valid after the `if` (it isn't).

The `match` in the question takes ownership of `bag.food` (invalidating `bag`) because it has a branch that takes ownership. If you want that particular branch to not take ownership, you can use a `ref` pattern to borrow instead:

```
match bag.food {
    Food::Cake => println!("I got cake"),
    ref x => println!("I got {:?}", x)
}
```

Alternatively, since Rust 1.26 the compiler knows how to bind value patterns (such as `Food::Cake`) to references (such as `&bag.food`), so you can write:

```
match &bag.food {
    Food::Cake => println!("I got cake"),
    x => println!("I got {:?}", x)
}
```

In this case `Food::Cake` matches the value, but `x` matches and is bound to the reference, so it does the same thing as the previous snippet with `ref`. (You may see this referred to as "default binding modes" or "match ergonomics".)