# "if" statement gets executed when the condition is "false" in a Rust program, how to understand it?

Tags: if-statement, scope, rust, borrowing

For the following Rust program:

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo = "test".to_string();
    if false {
        let _bar = foo; // value moved to _bar
    }
    println!("{}", foo);
}
```

I got this error when run it:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `foo`
 --> src\main.rs:6:20
  |
2 |     let foo = "test".to_string();
  |         --- move occurs because `foo` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
3 |     if false {
4 |         let _bar = foo; // value moved to _bar
  |                    --- value moved here
5 |     }
6 |     println!("{}", foo);
  |                    ^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Could anyone help to explain what happens here? It's weird to me that the *move* happens in a if statement which will never be true. Also I want to know more about this situation, what keywords should I use to search?

Comment: Rust doesn't try to build the control flow to check ownership. It will be too time-consuming, and compilation times are sometimes already large.

Comment: You are confusing compile time with runtime behaviors. And at compiling time, the tasks of `rustc` are divided into passes, the borrow check is one albeit rather famous one. The dead code like this will certainly be eliminated by later passes if in release mode but it still is an error nonetheless in borrow check pass. Run `rustc +nightly -Ztime-passes hello_world.rs` and you'll be amazed how many passes there are!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the secret to *moves*: they don't really exist.

Moves generate no code (in the sense of machine code) that is different from a bitwise copy.¹ The only difference between a move and a copy is what happens to the "original": if it's still valid, it's a copy; if the original is no longer valid, it's a move.

So how does the compiler enforce that you don't use the original value after a move? There's no runtime flag that keeps track of whether `foo` is valid or not.² Instead, the compiler uses source code analysis to determine, at compile time, whether `foo` is definitely valid or may have been moved out of when you try to use it. Because this analysis takes place at compile time, it doesn't follow the flow of execution within the function; it happens for the whole function at once. The compiler sees that `foo` is moved out of inside the `if`, and rejects the later use of `foo` without evaluating the condition or any code.

A smart compiler *could* take control flow into account when doing validity analysis,³ but that might not be an improvement. It's not always possible to know whether a branch is taken (it's [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem)), so there would be cases where the compiler would still get it wrong. Also, as Cerberus noted in the question comments, it would greatly slow down that compiler pass.

Put another way: In Rust, you never explicitly move something. You just do whatever you want with it, and let the compiler tell you whether you did it wrong or not, according to whether the type is `Copy` and whether it's used later. This is unlike C++, where moving is an operation that may call a "move constructor" and have side effects; in Rust, it's a purely static, pass/fail check. If you did it right, the program passes and moves on to the next stage of compilation; if you did it wrong, the borrow checker will tell you (and hopefully help you fix it).

#### See also

- [What are move semantics in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288782/what-are-move-semantics-in-rust)
- [Runtime vs Compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time)

---

¹ Unless the moved type implements `Drop`, in which case the compiler may emit [drop flags](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nomicon/drop-flags.html).

² Actually, there *is* (the drop flag), but it's only checked when `foo` is dropped, not at each use. Types that don't implement `Drop` don't have drop flags, even though they have the same move semantics.

³ This is similar to how null checking works in Kotlin: if the compiler can figure out that a reference is definitely non-null, it will allow you to dereference it. Validity analysis in Rust is more conservative than that; the compiler doesn't even try to guess.